# eregi to preg_match

Tags: regex, preg-match, eregi

I am using a lib which uses

```
$pattern = "LIMIT[^\w]{1,}([0-9]{1,})([\,]{0,})([0-9]{0,})";
        $replacement = "";
        eregi($pattern, $query, $regs);
        $query = eregi_replace($pattern, $replacement, $query);

        if($regs[2])
            $query = str_ireplace("SELECT ", "SELECT TOP ".$regs[3]." ", $query);
        else
            {
            if($regs[1])
                $query  = str_ireplace("SELECT ", "SELECT TOP ".$regs[1]." ", $query);
            }
```

I change some part of the code to

```
$pattern = "/LIMIT[^\w]{1,}([0-9]{1,})([\,]{0,})([0-9]{0,})/i";
        $replacement = "";
        preg_match($pattern, $query, $regs);
```

But now I got error messages saying "Undefined offset: 2" and "Undefined offset: 1"

I think moving from eregi to preg_match should be easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with `preg_match` or `preg_replace` or your regex.

You get this error when `$query` doesn't match at all (e.g. `$query="SELECT foo FROM bar"`).
Then `$regs` is an empty array, so accessing `$regs[2]` results in an error since there are no elements in it to begin with.

I'd suggest using `count($regs)` to see whether to even do the `$regs[2]` thing.

```
$query="SELECT asdf FROM foo";
$pattern = "/LIMIT[^\w]{1,}([0-9]{1,})([\,]{0,})([0-9]{0,})/i";
$replacement = ""; 
preg_match($pattern, $query, $regs);
$query = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $query);


if( count($regs)>=0 ) {
    if($regs[2])
    // ... etc the #$egs[2] $regs[1] code here.
}
```